# Atom.io | How to edit CSON file

Tags: text-editors, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am trying to edit my language-php/grammars/php.cson file in order to resolve an issue with syntax highlighting. However, I cannot seem to find this on my Windows installation of Atom.io ...

It is not available in Users/User/.atom/packages/

Comment: @Biswapriyo I installed it with an installer

Comment: Did you try this article? https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/

Comment: @Biswapriyo If you make that an answer I will accept it.

Comment: If that article works then you **make your answer yourself with details**. I don't use Atom. I'm happy with Notepad++ and C/C++. So I don't know about the details.

Comment: Also no need to attribute my name or my comment in answer. I'll delete the comments.